# Convert char to int, do magic, convert to char again?

Tags: java, char, int

I started my first programming lessons a few weeks ago and the homework is driving me a little crazy lol. Was wondering if you could lend me a hand here :}

Basiclly I need setup a program that creates a char vector (size n) that starts with a specific letter and fills the rest to the following letters, like so: sequence('c', 3) → {'c', 'd', 'e'}

what's wrong with my code ?

```
class Aula6{
    static char[] sequence(char c, int n){
        char[]v=new char[n];
        v[0]=c;
            for (int i=1;i<n;i=i+1){
                v[i] = (char)((int)v[i]+1);         
            }
            return v;       
    }
}
```

I hope i was sufficiently clear, my english is terribad :S

Comment: Can't you use a `std::vector`? This is C++ right?

Comment: what's the language? java?

Comment: @gsamaras no Semi-colon followed by the end of the class definition,so I guess it's java .

Comment: That might be the case chinese letters, but SO is not a site for guessing. terribad question, -1, close vote!

Comment: It's Java. Sorry about the confusion. Added the tag :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you might write it;

```
static char[] sequence(char c, int n) {
    char[] ret = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ret[i] = c++;
    return ret;
}
```

Java will do the casting for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks dude :) that did it

Comment: @Kaynrath can you see that `c++` did everything you needed very simply. ;)

Comment: Yeah. I was trying the "newbie" way of doing it i guess x)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you were having was your index was off. For example you were trying to set the value of v[1] to 1 more than what v[1] was previously, not one more than what v[0] is. Java automatically sets the values of an array to a 'zero value', in this case `(char)0`.  So v[1] goes from `(char)0` to `(char)1`. The problem with your solution is that you're off by one when indexing. If you did a `System.out.println(v);` you would only see the first character.  That's because the most of the first 32 (I think) ASCII characters are control characters and often aren't displayed when printed.  As Peter Lawrey mentioned Java can handle a lot of the casting for you.

```
public static char[] sequence(char c, int n) {
    char[] v = new char[n];
    v[0] = c;
    for(int i = 1; i < n ;i++) {
        //To see what's going on with your methodology
        //System.out.println( "Initial: " + (int)v[i]);
        //v[i] = (char)((int)v[i]+1);
        //System.out.println( "Updated: " + (int)v[i]);

        //This would fix your code
        v[i] = (char)((int)v[i-1] + 1);  //not v[i] 
    }
}
```